# How can I add spacing around a Flex DataGrid drop-in Button itemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, coding-style, padding, itemrenderer

I have a `DataGrid` with an drop-in `Button` `itemRenderer`:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="" width="135" 
    itemRenderer="ActionButtonItemRenderer" />
```

However, the button extends all the way both the right and left edge of the `DataGridColumn`. I've tried messing with the `width` properties and `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` styles of both the `DataGridColumn` and the `itemRenderer`, but nothing seems to work.

NOTE: I do not want to use a `Container` or `UIComponent` with the Button as a child as the itemRenderer - too much code.

Is there a ***simple*** way to add left and right padding?

Comment: why do you say using a Container or UIComponent is too much code? Are you saying from a readability standpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The button should only be as wide as you specified when you created it as a component, unless you created the component with 100% as the width. So, try a different percent width, a fixed pixel value, or (as you said you don't want to do) using a canvas based item renderer component with a button positioned inside of it.

Comment: As I stated in the original question, setting an explicit width on either - or both - the itemRenderer Class and the DataGrid Column has no effect on the size of the Button. It simply fills the column width.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about 'simple'... but it doesn't require a new class.

public var itemRenderer:ClassFactory ;

[...]

itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(ActionButtonItemRenderer);
itemRenderer.properties = "{width:135}";

[...]